# SAS: How to convert from a lower frequency time series to higher one

Tags: sas, time-series

For example:

```
date       value
1/1/1990     1
1/1/1991     2
```

What I want as a result is

```
date       value
1/1/1990     1
2/1/1990     1
3/1/1990     1
...
1/1/1991     2
2/1/1991     2
3/1/1991     2
...
```

I have investigated the `PROC EXPAND` procedure, but it does not do what I desire. Not sure how to do something as simple as this in an efficient manner.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with PROC EXPAND, but it's also trivial in the data step.

```
data want;
  merge have have(firstobs=2 rename=(date=last_date) keep=date);
  if not missing(last_date) then do date=date to (last_date-1);
    output;
  end;
  keep date value;
run;
```

That's a lookahead merge, where you merge the dataset to itself with one row removed from the top.

It wouldn't work for the last row, unless you either a) added an extra final row, or b) wrote a rule to specifically apply to the last row.

It also might be more easily written than this, if you're always converting the line from the 1st of the year to the last of the year.

```
data want;
 set have;
 do date = date to intnx('Year',date,1,'s');
  output;
 end;
run;
```

To do this with PROC EXPAND, you would do this:

```
proc expand data=have out=want from=year to=day method=aggregate;
 id date;
run;
```

Again, it needs a 'final' row added in order to do what you want - it won't go past the last observed row; but that doesn't seem difficult if that's desired.  I would use the 2nd method here if you have fixed time intervals, and either of the other methods if your time intervals are not fixed (and add a final observation if desired).